# How to add a method to functionalized module.exports

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

**Question**. How to add a method to functionalized `module.exports` in my [addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)?

I want to execute following Node code.

```
const hello = require('./build/Release/hello')
hello((msg) => { console.log(msg) })    // prints 'hello world'
console.log('hello', hello.hello())     // prints 'hello world'
console.log('3 + 5 =', hello.add(3, 5)) // prints '3 + 5 = 8'
```

Following is core C++ code.

```
#include <node.h>

namespace hello {
    using v8::Exception;
    using v8::Function;
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Null;
    using v8::Number;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Value;

    void hello(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
    }

    void add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

        if (args.Length() < 2) {
            isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
            return;
        }

        if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
            isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
            return;
        }

        double value = args[0]->NumberValue() + args[1]->NumberValue();
        Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, value);

        args.GetReturnValue().Set(num);
    }

    void runCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
        const unsigned int argc = 1;
        Local<Value> argv[argc] = { String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world") };
        cb->Call(Null(isolate), argc, argv);
    }

    void init(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object> module) {
        // TODO: It doesn't seem correct code.
        NODE_SET_METHOD(module, "exports", runCallback);
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", hello);
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "add", add);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(hello, init);
}
```

But it throws some errors.

```
console.log('hello', hello.hello())
                       ^

TypeError: hello.hello is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello\test.js:3:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (node.js:348:7)
    at startup (node.js:140:9)
    at node.js:463:3
```

Throwing same errors is continued if I comments line 3.

```
TypeError: hello.add is not a function
```

But it prints 'hello world' when I comments line 3 and 4.

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you overwrite the export property on the module with your runCallback that's what ends up being returned when you require it.  Doing NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", hello); is adding the hello function to the original export object - which is *not* being returned.

You have to choose - either add functions to the module's export, or overwrite the module's export - but not both.

Comment: Hmm... so equivalent to `var foo = function(){}; foo.bar=0; module.exports = foo` is impossible in C++?

Comment: No - you need to add it to runCallback though.